# Making HTTPRequest and getting response (Adobe Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

Im trying to make a HTTP Request in Adobe Flex (Actionscript) as follows:

```
var p:PersonSearchController = new PersonSearchController();
showAlertDialog();
p.search(sc);
alert.cancel();

navigator.pushView(views.PersonSearchResults, +p.getResp());
```

So basically, before the search we get a "Searching..." AlertDialog box, once the search is complete, the dialog box disappears and the results screen is pushed onto the screen...

Here is the search method:

```
function search{
var requestSender:URLLoader= new URLLoader();

dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

var urlRequest :URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://airpoint05:8888/MPS2/PersonSearch");

var msg:String = "blah";

/* Setup HTTP Request */
urlRequest.data = msg;
urlRequest.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
requestSender.load(urlRequest);
}
```

And here is the completeHandler function:

```
/* URL has completed and got a response */
private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var response:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    this.res = URLLoader(event.target).data;
    trace(this.res);
    response.close();   
}
```

When this line is called: navigator.pushView(views.PersonSearchResults, +p.getResp());

p.getResp() is nothing as the response hasn't came back yet. I want the program to basically block until the HTTPResponse is received so I can process the results. At the moment the Popup appear and disappears quickly, and in the background the search goes off and makes the request... I get the response but only after the results screen has been pushed out. How can I make the popup block until we have a HTTPresponse?

Thanks
Phil

Comment: Thanks guys, Ill try this tomorrow in work. One problem I was getting was that the 

"navigator.pushView(views.PersonSearchResults, +p.getResp());"

couldn't be called from the controller, it had to be called from the view, not sure if this will cause any issues but ill post the results tomorrow, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use URLLoader for this, use HTTPService:

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
private function search(text:String):void
{
service.send({search:text}); // your service will receive the variable 'search' with your string
}

private function resultHandler(e:ResultEvent):void
{
var data:Object = e.result;
// do whatever else here
}
]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:HTTPService id="service" method="POST" url="http://airpoint05:8888/MPS2/PersonSearch" result="resultHandler" />
```

Comment: Agreed I like this better than my answer +1, leaving mine for anything it adds.  At first I was questioning the don't use URLRequest... but thinking about it more and looking at it I don't see why you wouldn't just use HTTPService unless you're trying to avoid mx (like in a preloader).

Answer (score 0):

HTTPService/URLRequest (any remote calls) are by design asynchronous, requests across a network take a variable amount of time so there's no saying how long a user would have to sit with their machine/process/plugin locked up before the request returns.  What you should do instead is pop up a loading dialog at the time the request is made then move your code for showing the other pop-up (and closing the loading dialog) into the complete handler.  Basically move this:

alert.cancel();

navigator.pushView(views.PersonSearchResults, +p.getResp());

into the complete handler and make p a private local variable (if you need to instantiate it in advance or set properties on it).