# HTTP GET from socket multiple events?

Tags: actionscript-3, http, sockets, air

How do you know if a socket server or web server is done transmitting a HTTP GET request when using ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA ? 
I doing my socket request with socket.writeUTFBytes('GET /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\n'); 
But the 'answer' is so big that i get multiple ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA. How do i know how much data it is supposed to transmit to me ? Or when it's done transmitting ?? Or even how many progressEvents i will get out of this request ? So far I'm using a timer that checks if the server is still transmitting but this isn't a very clean way of doing things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i know how much data it is supposed to transmit to me? Or when it's done transmitting ??

By reading the `Content-length` header if that is sent by the server, or by waiting until the server closes the connection, or by reading until you've encountered a last-chunk (`0<CRLF><CRLF>`) if chunked transfer encoding is enabled, or [any of the other indications that a full response has been received](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4).

For simplicity, use a [HTTPService](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5475920/266143) or if that doesn't fit your needs, use a [library that implements an HTTP client](http://code.google.com/p/as3httpclientlib/).

> Or even how many progressEvents i will get out of this request ?

There is no way to tell.

Comment: Thanks i'll try the CRLF way :)

Comment: @Eric that won't work unless chunked transfer-encoding is enabled. Please don't only read the parts of my answer that you like, but try to understand what I'm telling: implementing an HTTP client is not trivial and error-prone; you should use a library from someone who already did so.